# An integral with $2017$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

As a Happy New Year card for Stack Exchange communities goes this problem.

Prove the equality
$${{\large\int_{-2017}^{2017}\left(\frac{\large\displaystyle\sqrt[2017]{x-2017}}{\space\large\displaystyle\sqrt[2017]{x-2017}+\large\displaystyle\sqrt[2017]{x+2017}\space }\right)dx=2017}}$$

Comment: Dear @Piquito: How do you come up with such integrals? Last year also you asked such question which can be found                                                   [here] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595361/an-integral-for-the-new-year?rq=1).

Comment: @Arpit Kansal: Yes but this integral is not of the same form. This is very easy to solve despite appearances. Best regards.

Comment: Dear @Piquito: I know its easy but i was just interested how do you construct such integrals?

Comment: I am also interested.

Comment: See the used property in Olivier Oloa's answer. Notice that the exponent can be arbitrary, not just $\frac{1}{2017}$. Also you can use the quite simple change of variable $x=-t$

Comment: Very nice! (+1). Would it work with $2018$ as well? :)

Comment: @hypergeometric One has to be careful with the meaning of $\sqrt[2018]{x-2018}$ when $x<2018$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa - Ok, so it will work for $2019$ but perhaps not $2018$...? :)

Comment: @hypergeometric: Put                                                                                              integral between -2018 and 2018 of ((2018-x)^(1/2018))/((2018-x)^(1/2018)+(2018+x)^(1/2018))                                                                                              in Wolfram and you will have the answer.

Comment: @Piquito Yes, it works since in your above comment $2018-x\ge0$ for $-2018\le x \le2018$ whereas $x-2018\le0$ (as in the OP integral) doesn't work for $-2018\le x \le2018$. That's why I said to be careful with the initial integral in case we replace $2017$ by $2018$.

Comment: Clearly the integral must be calculated where the domain of the involved function allows it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One may use the property
$$
\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_{a}^bf(a+b-x)\ dx
$$ applied to
$$
f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[2017]{x-2017}}{\sqrt[2017]{x-2017}+\sqrt[2017]{x+2017}\space }, \quad a=-2017,\quad b=2017,
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
I=\int_{-2017}^{2017}\frac{\sqrt[2017]{x-2017}}{\sqrt[2017]{x-2017}+\sqrt[2017]{x+2017}}\ dx&=\int_{-2017}^{2017}\frac{\sqrt[2017]{-x-2017}}{\sqrt[2017]{-x-2017}+\sqrt[2017]{-x+2017}}\ dx
\\\\&=\int_{-2017}^{2017}\frac{\color{red}{-}\:\sqrt[2017]{x+2017}}{\color{red}{-}\:\sqrt[2017]{x+2017}\color{red}{-}\:\sqrt[2017]{x-2017}}\ dx
\\\\&=\int_{-2017}^{2017}\frac{\sqrt[2017]{x+2017}}{\sqrt[2017]{x+2017}+\sqrt[2017]{x-2017}}\ dx
\end{align}
$$ thus
$$
2I=I+I=\int_{-2017}^{2017}\frac{\sqrt[2017]{x-2017}+\sqrt[2017]{x+2017}}{\sqrt[2017]{x-2017}+\sqrt[2017]{x+2017}}\ dx=\int_{-2017}^{2017}\ dx=2\cdot 2017
$$ that is
$$
I=2017.
$$

Comment: +1,last year question was also the direct application of same formula!(See my comment)

Comment: @Olivier: See the comment for hypergeometric above

Answer (score 3):

$$\text{If }J=\int_a^b\frac{g(x)}{g(x)+g(a+b-x)}dx,\ J=\int_a^b\frac{g(a+b-x)}{g(x)+g(a+b-x)}dx$$

$$\implies J+J=\int_a^b dx$$ provided $g(x)+g(a+b-x)\ne0$

If $\displaystyle f(x)=\sqrt[2n+1]{x-2017}, f(2017-2017-x)=-\ \sqrt[2n+1]{x+2017}$

For [An integral for the New Year](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595361/an-integral-for-the-new-year?rq=1),

if $\displaystyle  g(x)=\sqrt[2n+1]{3\cdot2016-x},\ g(3\cdot2016+2016-x)=\ ?$